# How to debug Uncaught exception: Error without stack trace reported by testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'd like to find a way to debug JavaScript errors reported by `testcafe`. It's not a big problem locally where we can just look into browser's console and read errors. It's a bit more complicated in continuous integration environments in headless browsers.

At the moment tests are run:

- locally // always succeed, the problem doesn't exist
- locally in docker // always succeed, the problem doesn't exist
- **circleci in docker // sometimes fail**

As written above, tests always succeed locally and it doesn't matter whether they are run inside or outside docker. The problem is with tests that are run on circleci and sometimes they fail. They fail because of uncaught JavaScript error and `testcafe` reports the error like below:

```
<failure>
  <![CDATA[
    1) Uncaught exception:

       Error:

       Browser: HeadlessChrome 77.0.3865 / Linux 0.0.0
  ]]>
</failure>
```

There is no stack trace, no message, no info, **no screenshot**. It's really hard to debug because it only occurs on circleci environment.

I was trying to use built-in client-side code injection from `testcafe` to bind into `onerror` / `addEventListener('error')` like in examples here: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399515/accumulate-all-js-warnings-and-errors-during-test-runs-in-testcafe), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790703/is-there-a-way-to-capture-js-errors-but-not-fail-testcafe-tests-because-of-them). Unfortunately nothing is reported.

At the moment the logging mechanism on my side look like this

```
fixture('Profile - remove account')
  .page(url('/sign-up'))
  .beforeEach(resize)
  .afterEach(async t => {
    console.log(await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages());
  });

test(`should:
  ▹ Sign up
  ▹ Visit /profile/account
  ▹ Remove current account
  ▹ Visit /login
`, async t => {
```

**log.js**

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (error) {
    console.error('Got uncaught error');
    console.error(error.message);

    try {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    catch (_) {
    }
});
```

**CLI**

```
docker-compose run --rm e2e \
  "chromium:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage" \
  tests/e2e/src \
  --cs=tests/e2e/log.js \
  --skip-js-errors \
  -S -s /tests/screenshots \
  -r xunit:/tests/test-results/testcafe/results.xml
```

This issue has been already reported several times:

- https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3183
- https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4708

I'm using [official testcafe docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/testcafe/testcafe/1.6.0/images/sha256-7281c6e1db5f2611f9a1a86a791ec86cbe0ca21dbb30748ceaf5e085759ba60a?context=explore).

Answer (score 2):

I guess an empty error stack is displayed for two reasons:

- the error is not related to any TestCafe action (`click`, `typeText`, etc.).
- the error has non-standard properties.

This error is raised on the server-side, so the `window.addEventListener('error')` handler doesn't help find the cause of the problem.

Before start your tests, your need to log the Node.js errors in the following way:

```js
export function registerErrorHandlers () {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', e => console.error(e));
    process.on('uncaughtException', e => console.error(e);
}
```

If you find the problematic case, please add information about it to [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5222) issue in TestCafe repository on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks! Could you point a place in documentation or basically where I can find any information how should I run or pass exported function `registerErrorHandlers`?

Comment: Run registerErrorHandlers before starting your tests

`registerErrorHandlers();`
`createTestCafe().then(tc => tc.createRunner().src('tests').browser('chrome').run())`